# Strong Pseudoprime to base square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

Question:

> Let n>1 be an odd composite integer and let a be an integer with (a,n)=1.
>
> Show that, if n is a strong pseudoprime to base a, then n is also a strong pseudoprime to base $a^2$

What I have done is that : let $n-1=2^{s}t$ then assumption implies that

$1. a^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$ or
$a^t \equiv -1 \pmod n$ or

$2.a^{2t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$
or... $a^{2^{s-1}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

so by part 1, $a^{2t} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ or

by part 2, $a^{2t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$
or... $a^{2^{s-1}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

these two results means that $n$ is strong pseudoprime to base $a^2$

when(if) we have also that $a^{2^{s}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

but the last term always be false because $a^{2^{s}t} \equiv a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ by that (strong pseudoprime is fermat pseudoprime) so we don't need that $a^{2^{s}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

so n is also a strong pseudoprime to base $a^2$ .. is my opinion right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the strong pseudoprime test doesn't require that you test $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \bmod n$, but in any case that also works. Your proof basically works OK but gets a little unclear, perhaps because of the confusion between $a^{2k}$ and $(a^2)^k$.

So to restate the strong pseudoprime rule:

> Define $t,d$ with $t\cdot 2^d = n-1$ with $t$ odd.  $n$ is a pseudoprime base $a$ if either:
>
> 1. $a^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$
> 2. $a^{t\cdot2^k} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ for some $0 \le k \le (d-1)$

Note that these conditions also assure that $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ without further evaluation.

Now we assume that $a$ meets one of these conditions, and check that $b= a^2$ also meets them:

1. $a^t \equiv 1 \pmod n \implies  b^t = a^{2t} \equiv 1 \pmod n $ (condition 1 applies for $b$)
2. $a^t = a^{t\cdot2^0} \equiv -1 \pmod n \implies  b^t = a^{2t} \equiv 1 \pmod n $ (condition 1 applies for $b$)
3. $a^{t\cdot2^k} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ for some $1 \le k \le (d-1) \implies  b^{t\cdot2^(k-1)} = a^{t\cdot2^k} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ (condition 2 applies for $b$)

Hence $n$ is also a strong pseudoprime base $b=a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the strong pseudoprime test you calculate certain powers of a and there are conditions that certain powers should be 1 or -1 to make a composite n a Pseudoprime.

If we calculate powers of $a^2$ instead then -1 changes to $(-1)^2 = 1$ and 1 remains unchanged. And the conditions of the test are such that after changing -1 to 1 a number remains Pseudoprime.

There will likely be additional pseudoprimes; a^n might be -1 (no Pseudoprime) while (a^2)^n = +1 and n might be a Pseudoprime.